# Use Maska input mask with Vuetify 3 text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify 3 and [Maska](https://beholdr.github.io/maska/#/), which provides masking of input values. I need to put a mask for phone numbers on `v-text-field`.

The documentation describes how it works with a regular HTML input element, but I need to put the mask on the Vuetify `v-text-field` component. How to do it?

I tried:

```html
  <v-text-field
    label="Телефон"
    variant="solo"
    class="mt-3"
    clearable
    v-maska data-maska="+7(###)-###-##-##"
    v-model="form.phone"
    :error-messages="v$.form.phone.$errors.map(e => e.$message)"  
  ></v-text-field>
```

but it is not working. I have registered the directive with:

```
directives: { maska: vMaska }
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and solved it like this:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
import { vMaska } from "maska";

const options = { mask: '#-#' };
const myValue = ref('');
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field v-maska:[options] v-model="myValue"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked for me also. Thnx Leo

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an [option in the documentation](https://beholdr.github.io/maska/#/?id=options), where you can change the event and value processed by the Maska directive, and as you said, it does not seem to work with regular `modelValue`/`@update:modelValue`.

But you can [use Maska programmatically](https://beholdr.github.io/maska/#/?id=programmatic-use) and mask the input and unmask the output to `v-text-field`.

Just create a mask instance with

```
const mask = new Mask({ mask: '+7(###)-###-##-##' })
```

and in your `v-text-field`, replace `v-model` with updated  in- and output:

```html
      <v-text-field
        label="Телефон"
        :model-value="mask.masked(phone)"
        @update:model-value="value => phone = mask.unmasked(value)"
      ></v-text-field>
```

(Again, *make sure to remove `v-model`*)

It works in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const { Mask } = Maska
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      phone: ref('123'),
      mask: new Mask({ mask: '+7(###)-###-##-##' }),
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-text-field
        label="Телефон"
        variant="solo"
        class="mt-3"
        clearable
        :model-value="mask.masked(phone)"
        @update:model-value="value => phone = mask.unmasked(value)"
      ></v-text-field>
      Number: {{phone}}
   </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/maska@2/dist/maska.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: will this work with options api?

Comment: Yes, you just have to put the `mask` variable into the component's `data`